# Powershell remote manage Azure VM on seperate connected VNET's

Tags: powershell, azure, remote-access

I am trying to remote connect using powershell from one VM to another on my Azure network.

Each VM is on its own virtual network which are connected using VNET-to_VNET connections in either direction. I have also disabled all external ports for both VMs so they cannot connect with the outside world. I am RDPing on to them using a point-to-site VPN which is working correctly.

I have added each VM to the trustedhosts of the other VM using powershell and am trying to connect using the following command

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName SERVERINTERNALIP -credential SERVERCREDENTIALNAME
```

This returns the following error:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server SERVERINTERNALIP failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete
the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName SERVERINTERNALIP -credential SERVERCREDENTIALNAME
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (SERVERINTERNALIP:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I tested in my lab. I notice that when server disable WinRm Port 5985, I get the same error with you.

Base on my knowledge, please ensure the 5985 is listening in the Server VM, you could use the cmdlet to test.

> netstat -ant|findstr 5985

Secondly, **please open port 5985 in the server VM’s Firewall**.
[image]
**Notes: If you manage your VM by public IP, you should open port 5985 on both the VM’s and the subnet’s (if you configured) Network Security Group.**

Comment: Thank you. It seems that windows firewall was blocking this from working.